# Cannot run basic Windows commands using :terminal

Tags: gvim, terminal

I have the GVim 8.1 compiled with `+terminal` flag. After I enter Vim via `vim -u NONE`, I try to execute simple command, like `:terminal cd` or `:terminal dir` just to check the output. Instead of the command being executed, I get the `CreateProces failed` error. How can I debug this? Does anybody know what might be the cause of it?

I know I can use `:!<command>` syntax, but I'm testing the `terminal` syntax so that I can configure it in the future.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can `:terminal cmd.exe /c dir`

Comment: That's actually quite cool! I hope I can map `:terminal cmd` to what you just wrote :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir` and `cd` are not external utilities, but shell builtins. They cannot be executed directly. You have to open `:terminal` without parameters to run cmd.exe and only after that enter a command like `dir`.

Note that `:!` differs, as it prepends `:h 'shell'` and `:h 'shellcmdflag'` before your command automatically.